# Show custom widget with ScaffoldMessenger

Tags: flutter, dart

I’d like to have a widget in my application that operates much in the same way as a `MaterialBanner` with `ScaffoldMessenger`. But I’d like to customize the appearance of banner.

Is there a way that I can customize the appearance of `MaterialBanner`? In my initial experimentation I thought of extending it, but in the end I found that wasn’t really going to work. Also for a brief second I thought thought type casting a custom widget in my call to `showMaterialBanner` might work, but quickly ruled that out.

There's a few things I'm struggling to figure out how to address through the MaterialBanner widget, if it's still possible:

- I don't like (for lack of a better term) the grey overlay to the banner area that's applied. I'm not sure where to adjust that. I've tried setting the background color to white and transparent and it still shows up ultimately as an off white.
- Actions. I intend to make the actions within the banner content. currently I'm passing a `SizedBox.shrink()` per another SO question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Here is an [example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2a8e0b1f616074b805936b9f19fd6cd7) showing what I believe you are looking for.

A `MaterialBanner` is already customizable. Place your desired widget in the `content` param or actions list.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner(
  MaterialBanner(
    content: const Text('This is a MaterialBanner'), // <- This can be whatever you want
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentMaterialBanner(),
        child: const Text('DISMISS'), 
      ), // <- So can these
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Well, despite not mentioning it in my original question, it’s not just the appearance I want to customize per se. I don’t want any actions, at least in the way that MaterialBanner provides them. I found a similar question about providing no actions but the answer seemed a little hack-y.

Comment: Could you update your question to be more clear with what you are looking for?

Comment: How can I remove the semi-transparent overlay? When I don't pass in a background color, or when I pass in white, it's not the actual color of the background or white.

Comment: I've added an example that I think shows mostly what you are looking for. Feel free to play around with colors or update your question further.

Comment: The default Scaffold.backgroundColor and the fact that it wasn't set in my theme, was the source of the variance I was referencing. This got me going down the right path though.

Comment: I can't remove action's padding. MaterialBanner doesn't allow actions parameter to be empty, and always insert padding around that. I checked it is not customizable through the source. So.. is this really customizable?

Comment: You'll see in my example I wrapped an empty action with a SizedBox.shrink to remove the padding.

Answer (score 1):

you can change styles of MaterialBanner ( outer widget ) in your app theme :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  .
  .
  theme: ThemeData(
    .
    .
    .
    bannerTheme: MaterialBannerThemeData(
      backgroundColor: ,
      contentTextStyle: ,
      elevation: ,
      leadingPadding: ,
    ),
  ),
);
```

and if you want change structure of inner widget you can pass any widget to `content` :

```dart
MaterialBanner(
  content: Row(
    children: const[
      Icon(Icons.check),
      Expanded(
        child: Text('This is a MaterialBanner'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  actions: [
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentMaterialBanner(),
      child: const Text('DISMISS'),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: How can I remove the semi-transparent overlay?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar for standardization / reuse.  Creating a custom widget seemed more trouble than it was worth so I used a function instead.

```
MaterialBanner materialBannerException(BuildContext ctx, String msg) {
  return MaterialBanner(
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).hideCurrentMaterialBanner();
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Theme.of(ctx).colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).colorScheme.errorContainer,
    content: Text(
      msg,
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(ctx).colorScheme.onErrorContainer),       
    ),
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.error,
      color: Theme.of(ctx).colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
    ),
  );
}
```